# Capturing capacity planning in tfs 2017 to powerBI

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, capacity-planning

I am building TFS dashboard using PowerBI where I want to capture multiple things like sprint planning, velocity... etc. I was able to get all the data from warehouse database but only data which was I was not able to find is capacity planning.

Can anyone tell me from where we can fetch capacity planning..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kapil, any update on this case? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

It's not able to do this directly between TFS/Azure DevOps Server and PowerBI.

You could take a look at similar question  below:

- [Is it possible to connect Azure sprint capacity data into
  PowerBI?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Is-it-possible-to-connect-Azure-sprint-capacity-data-into/m-p/1138785#M517766)
- [Retrieve user capacity for an iteration with ODATA](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155450/retrieve-user-capacity-for-an-iteration-with-odata.html)

Instead, you may have to use [Rest API Capacities - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/Capacities/Get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to  get a team member's capacity.